# Custom conditions Parallel.For

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing

I know th following line

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 5, (j, u) => {});
```

equals

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){}
```

but what's the parallel code for

```
for (int i = 0; (i < x + y && i < z); i++)
```

Comment: This case isn’t covered. Just exit the code accordingly inside the function’s body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is a Parallel.While construct, which doesn't exist.  You can approximate the functionality using something like this:

```
public static void While( 
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Func<bool> condition, 
    Action<ParallelLoopState> body) 
{ 
    Parallel.ForEach(new InfinitePartitioner(), parallelOptions, 
        (ignored, loopState) => 
    { 
        if (condition()) body(loopState)); 
        else loopState.Stop(); 
    }); 
}
```

Stephen Toub has a blog about it [on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/12/9867246.aspx)

**Edit**:  Just to throw out another option, you can also use the LoopState to break out of the Parallel loop based on our condition.  Something like this (psuedo code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx):

> Parallel.For(0, n, (i, loopState) => {
>
> // ...
>
> if (!(i < x + y && > i < z))
>   {
>
> ```
> loopState.Break();
>
> return;
> ```
>
> } });

Comment: Note that such a `condition` delegate would need to be thread safe, and it doesn't look like that would be the case here, as it's based on the current iteration (data that can't really be safely accessed).  And if you don't know if there will be another iteration until the completion of the previous, then there is nothing at all to parallelize.

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.For` is not designed to represent such loops.  It is strictly designed to represent a number of iterations known from the start of the loop.

You'll need to compute the number of iterations that will be required before calling `Parallel.For` if you want to use it.  If you cannot reasonably do so, then you will need to use another means of parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd seperate the condition out, thus

```
for (int i = x; (i < x + y && i < z); i++)
```

Becomes

```
int n = z < x + y ? x + y : z;
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(x, n, (i) => { });
```

Comment: This assumes the values of `x`,`y`, and `z` are all known before the start of the loop, and never change within the loop.